# Compare between Apple Mac computers

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, imac, mac-mini, mac-pro

I am thinking about purchasing an Apple Mac computer. But I am confused between the different types of Apple Macs available. I am clueless how to make a choice.

Is there any website or a resource that I can check which lets me compare the different offerings? It would be nice if I can compare between different computers side-by-side to see how the features and specifications differ?

Comment: First make a list of the things you need, then do the comparison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple's official website has a compare section for Macs where you can compare between three different models of Mac simultaneously. You can access it by going to the following link:

- https://www.apple.com/mac/compare/

When making a purchase decision, the first distinction that you have to make is whether you are looking to buy a desktop or a laptop.

Broadly speaking, Apple currently makes three kind of laptops:

1. [MacBook Air](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/) - A 13" ultra-portable.
2. [13" MacBook Pro](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-13/) - A lightweight laptop for professionals.
3. [16" MacBook Pro](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/) - A spec heavy laptop geared towards users needing extreme performance.

and three kinds of desktops:

1. [Mac mini](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/) - A bare bones lunch-box size computer sans display, keyboard and mouse.
2. [iMac](https://www.apple.com/imac/) - A fully integrated desktop computer.
3. [Mac Pro](https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/) - An expandable desktop tower for users requiring extreme performance.

Once you have filtered down to the determine computers that you are looking to choose from, head over to the [Mac - Compare Models](https://www.apple.com/mac/compare/) web-page and select the desired ones. You can compare upto three different computers at a time.

Here's a comparison between a 16" MacBook Pro, a 13" MacBook Pro and a 21.5" iMac looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.